# Javascript SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Tags: javascript

I’ve looked around for a bit and I can't find much help elsewhere

The code is much bigger but I’ll put the important bits in & close to the error

```js
var debug = "0";

/* IF Table Spagetti */
if (debug !== "1") {
    console.log("Debug Mode enabled");
    var mapname = "datacore"; 

} else if (mapname == "bounce") {
    $("#map").html("Bounce");

} else if (mapname == "crossfire") {
    $("#map").html("Crossfire");

} else if (mapname == "datacore") {
    $("#map").html("Datacore");

} else if (mapname == "lambda_bunker") {
    $("#map").html("Lambda Bunker");
} else
    $("#map").html(mapname);
}
```

```html
<a id="map">Map ID</a>
```

If anyone has a solution I’ll be thankful

Comment: } else
    $("#map").html(mapname);
} should be } else {

Comment: In the last `else` you omitted the `{`

Comment: You should usually see the line number when you get errors like these

Comment: "I looked around for a bit" -- Looked for the Stack Overflow bookmark?

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes here with the same error message with Knockout, then take care not to use reserved words, such as delete (oops!), as your model Class member names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an opening bracket (`{`) after your `else`:

```
} else {
    $("#map").html(mapname);
}
```

I would **strongly** recommend using a linting tool such as [eslint](http://eslint.org/) to help track down syntax (and other) errors like this...makes it **much** easier to track bugs like these down.

Comment: thanks I'll also check ESIint out.

Answer (score 1):

`else` is missing opening curly brace

```
else {
    $("#map").html(mapname);
}
```